# What is the meaning of Community response as revised and replaced?

Tags: discussion, support, community-user

Recently I got many responses from [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) as shown in below image.

It says action as `revised` and `replaced http://stackoverflow.com/ with https://stackoverflow.com/`

I know Community a background process that helps keep this site clean!
But, I want to know what is the meaning of this response and why should they do it?

[image: Community response]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the [change from HTTP to HTTPS](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/).

Stack Exchange now uses HTTPS by default. It used to be that several things were still transferred via HTTP instead of HTTPS.
To make things go more smooth, all links on Stack Exchange that go to Stack Exchange sites are automatically changed to use HTTPS. The community user makes these automatic edits.

They also use 301 redirects from HTTP addresses to the new HTTPS addresses, to maintain the Google search ranking (as stated in the linked blog post).